# PHP Filter with HTML

Tags: php, html

i have created a filter within PHP but the current information for the table is not being displayed.

This is my code:

```
include_once '../dbconfig/DBConn.php';
    $con = DBConn::getConnection();

    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        $valueToSearch=$_POST['valueToSearch'];
        $query="SELECT  * FROM `empavailability` WHERE CONCAT(`employeeID`AND `week`AND`day`AND`shift) LIKE '%5'";
    }else{
        $query="SELECT * FROM `empavailability` WHERE `employeeID`AND `week`AND`day`AND`shift`";
        $search_res= filterTable($query);
    }

    function filterTable($query)
    {
        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb"); 
        $filter_res= mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        return $filter_res;
    }
```

The data is not being displayed, what have i done wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed that both `$_POST['search']` and `$_POST['valueToSearch']` are set? I'm not sure why you're setting the latter, as you never use it. You also should be using prepared statements.

Comment: I've never seen `concat` with `and` separators. Have you used that in the DB before? I'm also not clear what you want to do with `WHERE `employeeID`AND `week`AND`day`AND`shift``. You should use the manuals and add error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Here there may be 2 cases

**Case 1:**
What happens if goes inside $_POST['search']. Where is the code after that

**Case2:** 
Inside filter function you can modify mysqli_query to this:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
  {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

So that you can log the error. Good luck